# Using HttpWebRequest to grab a ReCaptcha?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Ive been working on this issue for a long time now, it seems impossible to grab a ReCaptcha trough HttpWebRequest

Example of a ReCaptcha: [Rene-Server - TopList -Voting](http://www.rune-server.org/toplist.php?do=vote&sid=8254&name=RunicX)

The captcha is generated [here](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LdIwrsSAAAAAKHnMqR20V32fL27MbkH_LR6vu8r)

Everytime you visit this link it will generate a new challange, I tried connecting to that page first and then entering that data onto the 'vote' page but you really need to enter the captcha that is displayed on the vote page.

Below url will give the static Captcha:

> http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=CHALLANGE-ID-FROM-CAPTCHAGENERATE-HERE

Example:

> 03AHJ_VuuUTviZ4Z12heHZwqqI9z7kfiW61C9gCjTo30uLLDMOhk2vHXI_k3uT88qHLCnQH6TgOe3lQF9oJDACGDQD0bKo--KpixmHzgyoiPpn1CGFCjk3dVQx5mmLPXS6sFe8vHRK3rUPj7Mk7ah5ZdKx8-clBamN1Tw1s4ceNTbxgGJg9D2pdJc)

I tried making a request to the vote page and then grab the source from the page but I didnt found any intresting in that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en" id="vbulletin_html">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.__CF=window.__CF||{};window.__CF.AJS={"ga_key":{"ua":"UA-1653591-1","ga_bs":"2"}};
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (!window.CloudFlare) { var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:1382465720,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/abv=2980380653/"},atok:"29553f6592ae5270a0c334d688d838b0",petok:"1b414fbbada58802b34de7cd1b5a5d39-1383129967-1800",zone:"rune-server.org",rocket:"0",apps:{"ga_key":{"ua":"UA-1653591-1","ga_bs":"2"}}}];var  a=document.createElement("script"),b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.async=!0;a.src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/abv=616370820/cloudflare.min.js";b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b);}}catch(e){};
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var RecaptchaOptions = {
   theme : 'blackglass'
};

var _0x397e=["\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65","\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74\x5F\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64","\x76\x6F\x74\x65\x5F\x73\x65\x73\x73\x69\x6F\x6E"];function s49gm65(){document[_0x397e[2]](_0x397e[1])[_0x397e[0]]=sf56gfs(_0x397e[3]);} ;

var _0xca54=["\x72\x75\x6E\x65\x2D\x73\x65\x72\x76\x65\x72\x2E\x6F\x72\x67","\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66","\x55\x52\x4C","\x3B","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x3D","\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72","","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65"];function sf56gfs(_0x7ea0x2){if(document[_0xca54[2]][_0xca54[1]](_0xca54[0])>=0){var _0x7ea0x3,_0x7ea0x4,_0x7ea0x5,_0x7ea0x6=document[_0xca54[5]][_0xca54[4]](_0xca54[3]);for(_0x7ea0x3=0;_0x7ea0x3<_0x7ea0x6[_0xca54[6]];_0x7ea0x3++){_0x7ea0x4=_0x7ea0x6[_0x7ea0x3][_0xca54[8]](0,_0x7ea0x6[_0x7ea0x3][_0xca54[1]](_0xca54[7]));_0x7ea0x5=_0x7ea0x6[_0x7ea0x3][_0xca54[8]](_0x7ea0x6[_0x7ea0x3][_0xca54[1]](_0xca54[7])+1);_0x7ea0x4=_0x7ea0x4[_0xca54[10]](/^\s+|\s+$/g,_0xca54[9]);if(_0x7ea0x4==_0x7ea0x2){return unescape(_0x7ea0x5);} ;} ;} ;} ;
</script>
<title>Rune-Server - TopList - Voting</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<meta id="e_vb_meta_bburl" name="vb_meta_bburl" content="http://www.rune-server.org"/>
<base href="http://www.rune-server.org/"/><!--[if IE]></base><![endif]-->
<meta name="generator" content="vBulletin 4.2.0"/>
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="runescape private server private-server rs cheat download client rs-server jagex"/>
<meta name="description" content="King of the runescape private server, come here to learn how to make your own and play on one today!"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.9.0/build/yuiloader-dom-event/yuiloader-dom-event.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    if (typeof YAHOO === 'undefined') // Load ALL YUI Local
    {
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="clientscript/yui/yuiloader-dom-event/yuiloader-dom-event.js?v=420"><\/script>');
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="clientscript/yui/connection/connection-min.js?v=420"><\/script>');
        var yuipath = 'clientscript/yui';
        var yuicombopath = '';
        var remoteyui = false;
    }
    else    // Load Rest of YUI remotely (where possible)
    {
        var yuipath = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.9.0/build';
        var yuicombopath = '';
        var remoteyui = true;
        if (!yuicombopath)
        {
            document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.9.0/build/connection/connection-min.js"><\/script>');
        }
    }
    var SESSIONURL = "s=bf3a20816fb36133c273ceceeb0b26ae&";
    var SECURITYTOKEN = "guest";
    var IMGDIR_MISC = "images/bluefox2/misc";
    var IMGDIR_BUTTON = "images/bluefox2/buttons";
    var vb_disable_ajax = parseInt("0", 10);
    var SIMPLEVERSION = "420";
    var BBURL = "http://www.rune-server.org";
    var LOGGEDIN = 0 > 0 ? true : false;
    var THIS_SCRIPT = "toplist";
    var RELPATH = "toplist.php?do=vote&amp;sid=8254&amp;name=RunicX";
    var PATHS = {
        forum : "",
        cms   : "",
        blog  : ""
    };
    var AJAXBASEURL = "http://www.rune-server.org/";
// -->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rune-server.org/clientscript/vbulletin-core.js?v=420"></script>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Rune-Server RSS Feed" href="http://www.rune-server.org/external.php?type=RSS2"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clientscript/vbulletin_css/style00011l/main-rollup.css?d=1380970710"/>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clientscript/vbulletin_css/style00011l/popupmenu-ie.css?d=1380970710" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clientscript/vbulletin_css/style00011l/vbulletin-ie.css?d=1380970710" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clientscript/vbulletin_css/style00011l/vbulletin-chrome-ie.css?d=1380970710" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clientscript/vbulletin_css/style00011l/vbulletin-formcontrols-ie.css?d=1380970710" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clientscript/vbulletin_css/style00011l/editor-ie.css?d=1380970710" />
    <![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clientscript/vbulletin_css/style00011l/additional.css?d=1380970710"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rune-server.org/clientscript/ncode_imageresizer_v1.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
NcodeImageResizer.MODE = 'enlarge';
NcodeImageResizer.MAXWIDTH = '600';
NcodeImageResizer.MAXHEIGHT = '0';
NcodeImageResizer.BBURL = 'http://www.rune-server.org';

vbphrase['ncode_imageresizer_warning_small'] = 'Click here to view the full image.';
vbphrase['ncode_imageresizer_warning_filesize'] = 'Click here to view the original image of %1$sx%2$spx and %3$sKB.';
vbphrase['ncode_imageresizer_warning_no_filesize'] = 'Click here to view the original image of %1$sx%2$spx.';
vbphrase['ncode_imageresizer_warning_fullsize'] = 'Click here to view the small image.';
// -->
</script>
<style type="text/css">.brTag1{height:0px;font-size:0px;}div.ncode_imageresizer_warning{display:inline-block;color:#4F4300;font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;background:#FFFACD url(images/misc/nCode.png) 6px 6px no-repeat;border:1px solid #FFEC7D;padding:6px 0px 6px 0px;margin-top:12px;//height:27px !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  resize: none;
  overflow:hidden;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
  text-align:center;
}</style>
<style type="text/css">.toplist_online{color:#FFFFFF;background:#262626;}.toplist_online:hover{background:#515151;}.toplist_offline{color:#FFFFFF;background:#E60000;}.toplist_offline:hover{background:#FF0000;}.toplist_affiliate{color:#FFFFFF;background:#614E00;}.toplist_affiliate:hover{background:#7A6200;}.servername{font-size:24px;//text-decoration:underline;
        color: #DADAFF;
     }.serverdetail{font-style:italic;}.table{border-collapse:collapse;}.table,th,td{vertical-align:text-top;border:1px solid #363636;padding:6px 6px 6px 6px;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1653591-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

(function(b){(function(a){"__CF"in b&&"DJS"in b.__CF?b.__CF.DJS.push(a):"addEventListener"in b?b.addEventListener("load",a,!1):b.attachEvent("onload",a)})(function(){"FB"in b&&"Event"in FB&&"subscribe"in FB.Event&&(FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create",function(a){_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","like",a])}),FB.Event.subscribe("edge.remove",function(a){_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","unlike",a])}),FB.Event.subscribe("message.send",function(a){_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","send",a])}));"twttr"in b&&"events"in twttr&&"bind"in twttr.events&&twttr.events.bind("tweet",function(a){if(a){var b;if(a.target&&a.target.nodeName=="IFRAME")a:{if(a=a.target.src){a=a.split("#")[0].match(/[^?=&]+=([^&]*)?/g);b=0;for(var c;c=a[b];++b)if(c.indexOf("url")===0){b=unescape(c.split("=")[1]);break a}}b=void 0}_gaq.push(["_trackSocial","twitter","tweet",b])}})})})(window);
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="above_body">  
<div id="header" class="floatcontainer doc_header">
<div><a name="top" href="http://www.rune-server.org/" class="logo-image"><img src="images/bluefox2/misc/logo.gif" alt="Rune-Server - The King Community of RuneScape Private Servers"/></a></div>
<div id="toplinks" class="toplinks">
<ul class="nouser">
<li><a href="register.php" rel="nofollow">Register</a></li>
<li><a rel="help" href="faq.php">Help</a></li>
<li>
<script type="text/javascript" src="clientscript/vbulletin_md5.js?v=420"></script>
<form id="navbar_loginform" action="login.php?do=login" method="post" onsubmit="md5hash(vb_login_password, vb_login_md5password, vb_login_md5password_utf, 0)">
<fieldset id="logindetails" class="logindetails">
<div>
<div>
<input type="text" class="textbox default-value" name="vb_login_username" id="navbar_username" size="10" accesskey="u" tabindex="101" value="User Name"/>
<input type="text" class="textbox default-value" tabindex="102" name="vb_login_password_hint" id="navbar_password_hint" size="10" value="Password" style="display:none;"/>
<input type="password" class="textbox" tabindex="102" name="vb_login_password" id="navbar_password" size="10"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="cookieuser" title="Remember Me?" value="1" id="cb_cookieuser_navbar" class="cb_cookieuser_navbar" accesskey="c" tabindex="103"/>
<input type="submit" class="loginbutton" tabindex="104" value="Log in" title="Enter your username and password in the boxes provided to login, or click the 'register' button to create a profile for yourself." accesskey="s"/>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="s" value="bf3a20816fb36133c273ceceeb0b26ae"/>
<input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" value="guest"/>
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="login"/>
<input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password"/>
<input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password_utf"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('navbar_password_hint', "display", "inline");
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('navbar_password', "display", "none");
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('navbar_username', "color", "#828282");
            vB_XHTML_Ready.subscribe(function()
            {
            //
                YAHOO.util.Event.on('navbar_username', "focus", navbar_username_focus);
                YAHOO.util.Event.on('navbar_username', "blur", navbar_username_blur);
                YAHOO.util.Event.on('navbar_password_hint', "focus", navbar_password_hint);
                YAHOO.util.Event.on('navbar_password', "blur", navbar_password);
            });

            function navbar_username_focus(e)
            {
            //
                var textbox = YAHOO.util.Event.getTarget(e);
                if (textbox.value == 'User Name')
                {
                //
                    textbox.value='';
                    textbox.style.color='#FFFFFF';
                }
            }

            function navbar_username_blur(e)
            {
            //
                var textbox = YAHOO.util.Event.getTarget(e);
                if (textbox.value == '')
                {
                //
                    textbox.value='User Name';
                    textbox.style.color='#777777';
                }
            }

            function navbar_password_hint(e)
            {
            //
                var textbox = YAHOO.util.Event.getTarget(e);

                YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('navbar_password_hint', "display", "none");
                YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('navbar_password', "display", "inline");
                YAHOO.util.Dom.get('navbar_password').focus();
            }

            function navbar_password(e)
            {
            //
                var textbox = YAHOO.util.Event.getTarget(e);

                if (textbox.value == '')
                {
                    YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('navbar_password_hint', "display", "inline");
                    YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('navbar_password', "display", "none");
                }
            }
            </script>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="ad_global_header">
</div>
<hr/>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar">
<ul id="navtabs" class="navtabs floatcontainer">
<li><a href="/index.php" class="navtab">Portal</a></li>
<li id="vbtab_whatsnew">
<a class="navtab" href="activity.php">What's New?</a>
</li>
<li id="vbtab_forum">
<a class="navtab" href="forum.php">Forum</a>
</li>
<li class="selected" id="tab_mja0_383">
<a class="navtab" href="toplist/">TopList</a>
</li>
<li><a rel="nofollow" href="/index.php?pageid=rules" class="navtab">Rules</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="globalsearch" class="globalsearch">
<form action="search.php?do=process" method="post" id="navbar_search" class="navbar_search">
<input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" value="guest"/>
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="process"/>
<span class="textboxcontainer"><span><input type="text" value="" name="query" class="textbox" tabindex="99"/></span></span>
<span class="buttoncontainer"><span><input type="image" class="searchbutton" src="images/bluefox2/buttons/search.png" name="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('navbar_search').submit;" tabindex="100"/></span></span>
</form>
<ul class="navbar_advanced_search">
<li><a href="search.php" accesskey="4">Advanced Search</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="body_wrapper">
<div id="ad_global_below_navbar"><div align="center"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-5897627310846259";
/* Leaderboard - Dark */
google_ad_slot = "1836680582";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div></div>
<form action="profile.php?do=dismissnotice" method="post" id="notices" class="notices">
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="dismissnotice"/>
<input type="hidden" name="s" value="s=bf3a20816fb36133c273ceceeb0b26ae&amp;"/>
<input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" value="guest"/>
<input type="hidden" id="dismiss_notice_hidden" name="dismiss_noticeid" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="url" value=""/>
<div class="outer_border">
<div class="inner_border">
<div id="vbseo_vhtml_0"></div>
</div></div>
</form>
<h4 class="blockhead">Server voting</h4>
<div class="blockbody" align="center" style="padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px; color:red; font-size:16px;"></div>
<div class="blockbody" align="center" style="padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;">
<div style="padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;" class="toplist_online" onclick="document.location = 'toplist.php?do=detail&sid=8254&name=RunicX'">
<font class="servername">Vote for RunicX!</font><br/><font class="serverdetail">New unleeched RSPS || Custom minigames || Pking || Skilling || Bossing || Dueling || Dice || 100% Up</font>
<br/><br/>
<img src="static/toplist/228196.gif" border="0"/>
</div>
<form method="post" action="">
<table align="center" width="325px">
<tr>
<td>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LdIwrsSAAAAAKHnMqR20V32fL27MbkH_LR6vu8r"></script>
<noscript>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LdIwrsSAAAAAKHnMqR20V32fL27MbkH_LR6vu8r" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
<textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
</noscript>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div align="center" style="padding:5px">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-5897627310846259";
/* TopList Vote */
google_ad_slot = "7338286446";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div>
<div align="center" style="margin: 10px;">
<input type="hidden" name="submit_check" id="submit_check" value=""/>
<input type="submit" class="button" id="fcf94aab35c41515f99b570d024514786ebcaa25" name="fcf94aab35c41515f99b570d024514786ebcaa25" value="VOTE!" onclick="javascript: s49gm65();"/></div>
</form>
</div>
<div style="clear: left">
<br/><div align="center"><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.statius.net/legacy/"><img border="0" height="90px" width="728px" alt="" src="http://www.rune-server.org/static/affiliate/7/164817.gif"/></a></div>
</div>
<div id="footer" class="floatcontainer footer">
<form action="forum.php" method="get" id="footer_select" class="footer_select">
<select name="styleid" onchange="switch_id(this, 'style')">
<optgroup label="Quick Style Chooser"><option class="hidden"></option></optgroup>
<optgroup label="&nbsp;Standard Styles">
<option value="6" class="">-- BlueFox</option><option value="9" class="">---- GoldFox</option><option value="10" class="">---- RedFox</option><option value="11" class="" selected="selected">---- Bright Bluefox</option><option value="1" class="">-- Default Style</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="&nbsp;Mobile Styles">
<option value="2" class="">-- Default Mobile Style</option><option value="8" class="">-- BlueFox-Mobile</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
</form>
<ul id="footer_links" class="footer_links">
<li><a href="http://www.rune-server.org/">Rune-Server</a></li>
<li><a href="archive/index.php/">Archive</a></li>
<li><a rel="nofollow" href="toplist.php?do=vote&amp;sid=8254&amp;name=RunicX#top" onclick="document.location.hash='top'; return false;">Top</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        // Main vBulletin Javascript Initialization
        vBulletin_init();
    //-->
    </script>
</div>
</div>  
<div class="below_body">
<div id="footer_time" class="shade footer_time">All times are GMT +2. The time now is <span class="time">12:46 PM</span>.</div>
<div id="footer_copyright" class="shade footer_copyright">

Powered by vBulletin&reg;<br/>Copyright &copy;2000 - 2013, Jelsoft Enterprises Ltd.
<br/><!-- google_ad_section_start(weight=ignore) -->Search Engine Optimization by <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.crawlability.com/vbseo/">vBSEO</a><!-- google_ad_section_end --><div>We are not affiliated with Jagex nor RuneScape. RuneScape is a registered trademarks of Jagex.</div><div>Image resizer by <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.sevenskins.com/" title="vBulletin Skins - vBulletin Services" target="_blank">SevenSkins</a></div><br/>
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.vbstyles.com">vBulletin Skins</a> developed by vBStyles.com

</div>
<div id="footer_morecopyright" class="shade footer_morecopyright">


Digital Point modules: <a rel="nofollow" href="https://marketplace.digitalpoint.com/sphinx-search-for-vbulletin-4.870/item" target="_blank">Sphinx-based search</a>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var vbseo_jshtml = new Array();
vbseo_jshtml[0] = "<ol>         <li class=\"restore\" id=\"navbar_notice_1041\">        If this is your first visit, be sure to     check out the <a href=\"faq.php\" target=\"_blank\"><b>FAQ</b></a> by clicking the      link above. You may have to <a href=\"register.php\" target=\"_blank\"><b>register</b></a>      before you can post: click the register link above to proceed. To start viewing messages,       select the forum that you want to visit from the selection below.</li>      </ol>";

for(var vi=0;vi<vbseo_jshtml.length;vi++)
if(fetch_object("vbseo_vhtml_"+vi))fetch_object("vbseo_vhtml_"+vi).innerHTML = vbseo_jshtml[vi];

//]]>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thats probably because the Captcha generator page is Iframe onto the Vote page?

This leaves us to 2 options:

***Option 1:***

Grab ALL the images from the page and save them somewhere and then search for the captcha (Not sure if this is even possible with Webrequest)

***Option 2:***

Somehow obtain the image trough the source code

Once you made a request to the page you need to stay on the connection else the captcha is changed on the next request.

Anyone could share information on this or providing code? Please dont tell me to use WebBrowser because thats garbage..

Anyone could share information on this or providing code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to break the captcha? If so there is some very interesting jscript in that source that you posted. Try altering the values of LOGGEDIN and SECURITY TOKEN with firebug for a start

Comment: @CurlyPaul, Yes I am trying to break the Captcha after. The LOGGEDIN and SECURITY TOKEN are for the login progress on the site, however I have nothing to do with that since you do not need to be logged in or anything. Thanks for your reply anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to follow this : Save the captca image to disk it will be a new image when you hit it using HTTPWEBREQUEST but it won't matter and get it solved yourself or api .On the original post send the new captcha challenge number with captcha text and it will work , i have done this similar for LinkedIN which also uses the same captcha .

Thank you

Comment: I tried this but maybe something went wrong, I will retry it. Thanks